# ObjectiveC framework in Swift app causing errors (MobFox ad network framework)

Tags: objective-c, swift, mobfox

I'm trying to implement MobFox ad network into my Swift app. The framework is built in ObjC which I'm not familiar with.

I have added my bridging header.

Im getting 2 errors which I cannot figure out. This is the code that is producing the errors:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MobFoxNativeAdDelegate {

...

    func nativeAdFailedToLoadWithError(error: NSError!) {
    }

    func nativeAdWasClicked() {
    }

    func nativeAdWasShown() {
    }

    func publisherIdForMobFoxNativeAdController(controller: MobFoxNativeAdController!) -> String! {
    return "PUBLISHER_ID_HERE"
    }

    func nativeAdDidLoad(ad: MobFoxNativeAd!) {
    }
}
```

These are the issues:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MobFoxNativeAdDelegate {
```

The above code causes an error: Type 'ViewController' cannot conform to protocol 'MobFoxNativeAdDelegate' because it has requirements that cannot be satisfied

I'm sure there are no other methods that I need to implement - unless Im mistaken.

The other issue is:

```
func nativeAdDidLoad(ad: MobFoxNativeAd!) {
}
```

On this line I get the following error: Use of undeclared type 'MobFoxNativeAd'

The strange thing is XCode doesn't suggest this method when typing, so it seems to be invalid. For example if I type native, xcode suggests nativeAdFailedToLoadWithError, nativeAdWasClicked and nativeAdWasShown - but it does not suggest nativeAdDidLoad.

However, it is a required method.

Looking at the ObjC framework this is what it contains:

```
@class MobFoxNativeAdController;
@class MobFoxNativeAd;

@protocol MobFoxNativeAdDelegate <NSObject>

- (NSString *)publisherIdForMobFoxNativeAdController:(MobFoxNativeAdController *)controller;

- (void) nativeAdDidLoad:(MobFoxNativeAd *)ad;

- (void) nativeAdFailedToLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;

- (void) nativeAdWasShown;

- (void) nativeAdWasClicked;

- (UIViewController*) viewControllerForNativeAds;

@end

@interface MobFoxNativeAdController : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *requestURL;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet __unsafe_unretained id <MobFoxNativeAdDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL locationAwareAdverts;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger userAge;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* userGender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* keywords;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* adTypes;

- (void)setLocationWithLatitude:(CGFloat)latitude longitude:(CGFloat)longitude;

- (UIView*)getNativeAdViewForResponse:(MobFoxNativeAd*)response xibName:(NSString*)name;

- (void)requestAd;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. It was caused by a bug in the framework. The file MobFox.h needed to import MobFoxNativeAd.h

Answer (score 0):

First, you appear to be missing your implementation of `viewControllerForNativeAds`, it is listed in the protocol and not in the code you posted.

Are you importing the framework module at the top of your .swift file?

Comment: no im not importing the framework module - I thought I should too, but isn't this handled by the bridging header? I've looked at an example project written in swift and it doesn't have an import either. Here's the project file: https://github.com/mobfox/MobFox-iOS-Demo/blob/master/MobFoxSwiftDemo/MobFoxSwiftDemo/ViewController.swift

Comment: I've added func viewControllerForNativeAds() -> UIViewController! { } I'm not sure if this is the correct implementation. It still doesn't resolve any of the issues though.